# Set default lane in Fastline file

Tags: fastlane

Is it possible to set default lane in Fastlane file? Just like `default_platform`. It will be nice to run building by `fastlane` command without arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not implemented by design, so that when you don't specify a lane, it will always list out the available lanes.